# Cannot return value - Expression Expected?

Tags: java, android

I'm having an issue with my `return Car;` I was under the impression it would return the "KEY_IMAGE" String.

KEY_IMAGE is a string which will be put inside a BitmapFactory:

```
byte[] logoImage = getLogoImage(IMAGEURL);

private byte[] getLogoImage(String url){
     try {
             URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
             URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();

             InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

             ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);
             int current = 0;
             while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                     baf.append((byte) current);
             }

             return baf.toByteArray();
     } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e.toString());
     }
     return null;
}

logoImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( currentAccount.accImage, 
        0,currentAccount.accImage.length));
```

My method which has an error is:

```
public Car getCurrentCar() {
    SQLiteDatabase db       =   getWritableDatabase();
    String sql              =   "SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_IMAGE + " FROM " + TABLE_CARS + "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    Cursor cursor           =   db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    Car car_current = new Car(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
        return null;
    } else {
        return Car;
    }
}
```

the return Car; is giving me the errors:

"Expression expected" and "cannot find symbol variable Car".

Would anyone be able to explain why I cannot return Car?

Edit:

```
public Car getCurrentCar() {

    SQLiteDatabase db       =   getWritableDatabase();
    String sql              =   "SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_IMAGE + " FROM " + TABLE_CARS + "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    Cursor cursor           =   db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
    Car car = null;

    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            car = new Car(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
            db.close();
    }
    return car;
}
```

Comment: declare **car** outside the if block and just before it.

Comment: remove else condition and post `return car_current;` there

Comment: If the cursor close throws an exception your DB will never be closed.  OUght to be enclosed in individual try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 2):

> Cannot find symbol: variable `Car`

That means that the compiler can't find a variable named `Car`.

```
return Car;
```

`Car` is a class, not an object. You must return an object (or a variable).

I think that is what you meant

```
return car_current;
```

But you have to declare that variable outside the `if`:

```
Car car_current = null;
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    car_current = new Car(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `car_current` inside another `if`, which has a different scope. That variable has no scope outside `if` block. You should declare it outside `if` if you want to make use of it outside the `if block.

Secondly, you are returning `Car` which is a class and hence it's not valid. Rather you may want to return `car_current` I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This is Java 101.

Try it like this:

```
// Why not pass in a Car id? 
public Car getCurrentCar() {
    // Bad form here.  Externalize these.
    SQLiteDatabase db       =   getWritableDatabase();
    String sql              =   "SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_IMAGE + " FROM " + TABLE_CARS + "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    Cursor cursor           =   db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});

    Car car = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        car = new Car(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));
    }
    // Wrong - close in a finally block.
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close(); // Wrong - close in a finally block.
    return car;
}
```

Comment: Hey Duffy, thanks for your quick response. I'm having a look over what you've written. I'm not sure what you mean by why not pass in a Car id? I am querying the KEY_ID inside the sql String, or should that be done within the method? getCurrentCar(id)?

Also, should I be using try and finally together?

Comment: Exactly.  I think it's better to pass that in.  And yes, you should be using try and finally together.  What about exceptions?  I'll bet there's a SQLException thrown by some of the methods you call, but you neither catch nor include it in method signature.  I'd recommend using PreparedStatement and not using Cursor.  There's no need for it.

Comment: I've edited my post with the changes you suggested + I added the try and finally. Am I right in thinking the if (cursor != null) Part should be in finally?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't use Cursor here.  I'd just write classic JDBC and use PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return car_current instead of Car. But the variable car_current is not in the scope, so you should define it outside the if statement.
Try this:

```
Car car_current = null;
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
     car_current = new Car(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));

}
//after some code you could return only car_current without control
return car_current;
```